# Slow performance with ItemsControl / TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I have performance issue with my wpf application. I am displaying a form with many textboxes (like 130 or so). It is a software where user can configure many states in three stages of a distiller machine.  The form consists of three sections (stages), each can have different number of states and some fixed amount of properties to setup. Each state gives user option to set 6 values(via textbox).

So if a stage consists of for example 7 states, then it has 7x6 + 5 (fixed amount) = 47 textboxes. So the 3 stages can show 141 textboxes (it will be less because only two stages can be visible rest can be scrolled down).

https://pasteboard.co/I8LiVxG.png

To display the states for each stage I am using ItemsControl with ObservableCollection binding. This is a bottleneck in VS performance profiler as the application spends too much time in layout (orange color).
When I swap the ItemsControl with StackPanel and fixed amount of states, the problem is gone.

https://pasteboard.co/I8Lhu37.png

Of course the UI is a bit more complex, there is a listbox with distiller processes and each process is displayed in detail with stages and states. I have also viewmodels and bindings, the states count can be changed runtime so there is ObservableCollection bound to the ItemsControl. None of this is causing the issue, i tried to turn off most of the mvvm code that resets the values or recreates collection of states.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Cuts}">                    
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <local:RunConfigControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
             </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

In the code above RunConfigControl is just a Grid with 6 textboxes and labels. Cuts is the name of the ObservableCollection.

What is the difference when I use just a fixed amount of controls in StackPanel and when I use ItemsControl with collection. There is also StackPanel when i look at the visual tree.

Also I know that the controls are rendering when not visible (I am not using virtualization) but there are not many states (between 2-10) and the number of stages is always 3. Also all the states need to be visible I don't need to show 3 states and scroll for 7 others. Also I see two and half stage on the screen so the one half of last stage rendering despite not visible should not be the problem.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Sounds like it's layout calculation is causing the problems. What happens if you change your itemscontrol to a listbox so you get virtualisation anyhow?  You might have to explicitly use a virtualising stackpanel in the listbox.  Can't recall if that's in there by default now or not.  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>

Comment: If I change it to listbox it is the same. I do not need virtualizing panel there because i will always show all states. They are not fixed number but they will be at most 12-15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an editable DataGrid. This could be bound to your observable collection. The benefit is that a textbox is only create when editing, otherwise a textblock is used. You can style your grid to look like your picture. You can also set the cell to edit mode on mouse down so only a single click is needed to enter a textbox (cell).

Here is an example. You could get the look you want by hiding the headers, and adding some cell padding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I need to test this. I did not mention all the features and capabilities of the application so that the question is simple and without any additional technical issues. The customer really likes the layout, it is actually suggested by him so the datagrid will need some layout changes to be more like the current desing. Also here are some issues like disabling rows or cells because this layout is also used when distill process is running and there are restrictions of editing. Lastly the number inserted should be decimals with specific formats so the grid cells should have this set.

Comment: This could all be done with a DataGrid. Use a converter to format your cells. You'll need to use a bit of code to prevent editing disabled cells.

Comment: I used DataGridTemplateColumn and the custom textbox control for cell editing Ihave used before. Now it is running fast and it has the validation and input edit rules I had in previous design. I only need to restrict the editing of rows / cells specificly as requested by design. Also I have some issue with updating value in cell when using textblock for cell readonly template (it is not using the correct value that is set in textbox when edited), but I will probably create new question for that. Thanks for help